# Array modifier with empty: is there a way to get "constant" scaling?

Tags: modifiers, geometry-nodes

I have a circle.

I add an array modifier with object offset to an empty.

I scale the empty and i get:

[image]

Is there a way to get constant distances of the circles? or adding a constant to the radius?

I am also open for a GN solution... ;)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve concentric circles this way for instance :

Begin with a simple new Mesh > Circle object.

[image]

Create a separate mesh object and add this as a new GN modifier :

[image]

Explanation :

Instance a line with an offset of exactly 1 in x direction, then use the x position as an index in order to change the point scale attribute accordingly. Then, move all points to the same place by setting position to (0, 0, 0).

Throw in a radius offset multiplier and the circle count as modifier inputs for flexibility.

You can get this result :

[image]

Note : You can get rid of the Attribute Separate node if you set the line offset to (1, 1, 1) and directly use the `position` attribute instead of the new `x` attribute but it's less readable imo :

[image]

Note : Even shorter, plug the offset directly into the Line node offset to get rid of the Attribute Math node.

[image]

Comment: great! what version are u using? because in my 3.0 alpha from today...i see the circles only in edit mode :(

Comment: ok, i think you took a beziercircle....that works ;)

Comment: @Chris Hmm, I used latest 2.93.1 version. I used a displace modifier with very low strength after the GN to turn the geometry "real" though

Comment: Eh? Why should displacement make the geometry 'real'? Is this logic, or a random workaround until GN matures?

Comment: @RobinBetts My guess is until you actually need to use a regular operation on GN geometry, it stays in this kind of "instanced" state where it's computationally more efficient to display

Comment: Hrrumph :). Been following GN Dev. I hope there's still room (it seems contested) to rethink the basic architecture.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a single vertex + **Array Modifier** (constant offset) + **Screw Modifier**:

[image]

Number of vertices per circle is the number of steps of the Screw modifier.

Comment: that's genius too! unfortunately i cannot give two checkmarks. And because Gorgious was faster...he got it. But i LOVE your solution!!! +10 (although i can only give +1)

Comment: @Chris.. I'll throw one in for you.. :)